# I'm attempting to force gzip compression on a page using GZipStream but the browser says I'm using unsupported compression

Tags: c#, asp.net, gzip, gzipstream

I'm tring to implement what Steve Souders discusses http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/07/12/velocity-forcing-gzip-compression/ about forcing gzip compression

I've got a module that's running this:

```
void context_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var app = sender as HttpApplication;

    var request = app.Request;
    var response = app.Response;

    if (CompressionUtils.GzipSupported(request) || CompressionUtils.GzipNotSupportedExplicitly(request)) 
    {
        return;
    }

    if (CompressionUtils.GzipSupportedExplicitly(request))
    {
        response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        response.AddHeader(HttpHeaderKey.ContentEncoding, "gzip");
        return;
    }

    response.Write("<iframe style=\"display:none;\" src=\"/CompressedPage.aspx\"></iframe>");
}
```

`CompressionUtils.GzipSupported` just checks for the 'accepts-encoding' header while 
`CompressionUtils.GzipSupportedExplicitly` and `CompressionUtils.GzipNotSupportedExplicitly` check for the cookie saying whether the browser really can read gzip

But when I load a page in Firefox I get this error:

> Content Encoding Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or
>   unsupported form of compression.

and in Fiddler it shows that the content-encoding header has been added but the content hasn't been compressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I was just binding too late, bound to `PostMapRequestHandler` instead of `PreSendRequestHeaders`.  Working fine now.